# How to search nearest place in array object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

the mongodb document 'contents' is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bd1ff410ea3c38386b9194"),
    "name" : "4Fingers",

    "locations" : [
            {
                    "id" : "locations1",
                    "address" : "68 Orchard Rd, #B1-07 Plaza Singapura, Plaza Singapura, Singapura 238839",
                    "phone" : "+65 6338 0631",
                    "openhours" : "Sunday-Thursday: 11am - 10pm \nFriday/Saturday/Eve of PH*: 11am - 11pm",
                    "loc" : [
                            "1.300626",
                            "103.845061"
                    ]
            }
    ],

    "comments" : [ ],
    "modified" : 1472271793525,
    "created" : 1472012276724,
    "createdby" : "Admin",
    "modifiedby" : "Admin",
    "createdipaddress" : "localhost",
    "modifiedipaddress" : null,
    "types" : "Restaurant",
    "category" : "FoodAndBeverages",
    "logo" : "logo4Fingers.png",
    "tags" : "western, chicken, restaurant, food, beverages"
}
```

I want to find the nearest place to my location that i get from HTML5 navigation. How do i query it? Data should be sorted in near to far order.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query mongodb geospatial data first you need a geo spatial index on your location field.

Your location field is a string, it needs to be a numeric type, you need to update your data accordingly.

Create your index on numerical location data:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "locations.loc" : "2d" });
```

Query:

```
var projection = {"locations.loc":1};

var query = {"locations.loc": {"$near":[1.300626, 103.845061], "$maxDistance": 0.5}};
db.collection.find(query, projection).pretty();
//result:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bd1ff410ea3c38386b9194"),
    "locations" : [
        {

        "loc" : [
            1.300626,
            103.845061
        ]
    }
    ]
}

var query2 = {"locations.loc": {"$near":[2.300626, 103.845061], "$maxDistance": 0.5}};
db.collection.find(query2, projection).pretty();
//result:
{}
```

The query result will be sorted always, with nearest as first document.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergiu Zaharie.

It's working.

Then how can i returned all the field instead of returning this field only.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bd1ff410ea3c38386b9194"),
    "locations" : [
            {
                    "loc" : [
                            103.845061,
                            1.300626
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

//edit

Solved.

i just clear the projection then it work like charm.

Thank you.